# grep string from alphabetically last files in subdirectories

Tags: grep

I need to look for the string "Total CPU time used" in a set of files that are generated in an iterative calculation within a great number of subfolders called `folder_A`, `folder_B`, `folder_C` and so on.

So in `folder_A` i would have

`file_1_1
 file_1_2
 file_1_3
 file_1_4
 file_1_5
 file_2_1
 file_2_2
 file_2_3`

next to some other files with different names. In `folder_B` there would be

`file_1_1
 file_1_2
 file_1_3
 file_1_4
 file_1_5
 file_2_1
 file_2_2
 file_2_3
 file_2_4
 file_2_5
 file_3_1`

and so on, so every subfolder would contain a different amount of iterative steps and thus a different number appending the last file. I think the way to go is using recursive `grep` sorting out the alphabetically last file, the code I've tried is:

`grep -r "Total CPU time used" */file_* | tail -1`

However this only gives me an output of the last file in the last directory `folder_Z`. How do I grep the string from all subdirectories so that `folder_A/file_2_3`, `folder_B/file_3_1` and so on are not skipped?

Comment: I think your question hints at a ``for`` loop... if it works, then yes that's what I need.

Comment: There are other files present that are named differently. I'm only interested in the files specified in the post.

Comment: OK but then, do you know that the files are sorted by default in [_lexicographical order_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) so `file_1_10` will sort _before_ `file_1_2` ? Do you want the last one in lexicographical order (e.g. `file_1_2`)or do you want the last one as in "sorted by version" (`file_1_10`) ?

Comment: Well the counting always stops at ``file_1_5`` and resumes with ``file_2_1``, so this should be no problem. But what I need would be ``file_1_10``.

Comment: In that case (file names contain only numbers between 1 and 9) you already have an answer that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `tail -1` that gives you the last line of the result of the `grep` call. This likely comes from a match in the last file in the last directory.

Instead, you will need to loop over the directories.  This is using `bash`:

```
for dir in folder_*/; do
    files=( "$dir"/file_* )
    grep -F 'Total CPU time used' "${files[-1]}"
done
```

This would iterate over the directories.  For each directory, the last file (in the dictionary order sense) is grepped for the string that you are searching for.

I'm using `-F` with `grep` as I'm looking for a fixed string and not a regular expression.

If you want to additionally get the filename of the file in the `grep` output, then either tag on `/dev/null` as a last argument to `grep` (`grep` will include the filename when matching across more than one file operand), or use `grep` with `-H`, if your `grep` supports it.

Comment: The last paragraph is especially helpful!